# Renpy indent line

Tags: renpy

```
I'm sorry, but errors were detected in your script. Please correct the
errors listed below, and try again.


File "game/script.rpy", line 113: Line is indented, but the preceding default statement statement does not expect a block. Please check this line's indentation. You may have forgotten a colon (:).
    scene bg room
    ^

Ren'Py Version: Ren'Py 7.6.0.23051307
Tue Jun  6 23:54:48 2023
```

This is all it keeps giving me while I try to change code

I just typed in a couple of things trying to copy some code down from another place and it did this

Comment: The error message you're encountering indicates an issue with the indentation and syntax in your Ren'Py script. The error message specifically points to a problem on line 113 in the file "game/script.rpy". The issue appears to be related to the scene statement.